# how to store the query result into a variable in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, stored-functions

I am new in mysql and I am writing the following function in phpmyadmin:

```
BEGIN
declare @var1 int;
declare @var2 int;

set @var1 = 0;
set @var2 = 0;

count(*) 
into @var1
from transactions 
where reg_date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 90 DAY) 
and reg_date <= CURDATE() = last_transactions;

count(*) 
into @var2
from account 
where exp_date > CURDATE() 
AND reg_date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 90 DAY);


return @var2/@var1;
END
```

I always receive 1064 errror. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need the `SELECT` keyword at the beginning of each query.

Comment: It should be `SELECT COUNT(*)`, not just `COUNT(*)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
BEGIN
declare @var1 int;
declare @var2 int;

set @var1 = 0;
set @var2 = 0;

select count(*) as count into @var1  
from transactions 
where reg_date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 90 DAY) 
and reg_date <= CURDATE() = last_transactions;

select count(*) as count into @var2
from account 
where exp_date > CURDATE() 
AND reg_date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 90 DAY);
return @var2/@var1;
END
```